# Problem with cURL to Powershell conversion

Tags: powershell, curl

I have been trying to convert the below cURL command to PowerShell so that I can use it on my script. I converted it but, every time I execute the command, it gives me error like in the screenshot.

**cURL command:** `curl -X POST "https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/api/v2/quick-scan/file?_timestamp=1585901455112" -H "accept: application/json" -H "user-agent: API_KEY" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "scan_type=all" -F "file=@xyz.png;type=image/png" -F "no_share_third_party=false" -F "allow_community_access=false"`

**converted powershell command:**

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;

$fileqq = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp\xyz.jpg"

Invoke-WebRequest "https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/api/v2/quick-scan/file" -Headers @{'accept' = 'application/json'; 'user-agent' = 'Falcon Sandbox' ; 'Content-Type' = 'multipart/form-data' ; 'api-key' = "API_KEY"} -Method Post -Body @{"scan_type" = "all"; "file" = "$fileqq" }
```

**[powershell command error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3r08.png)**

It would be helpful for me if someone pointed out the error or correct my converted command

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Why use `Get-ChildItem` where all you need is the complete file path and name?

Comment: Thank you for having a look at it. I was trying all the viable options to see if something works. All I need is to upload that file using POST method. However, unfortunately, nothing worked for me.

Comment: `$fileqq = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp\xyz.jpg"` returns a [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8) object or `$null` if the file could not be found. Not the string `"C:\temp\xyz.jpg"`

Comment: Oh my god, so stupid of me to ignore the return type is not a string. Thank you very much.
I also tried by directly giving the path in the command, but it did not give me expected results.

`Invoke-WebRequest "https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/api/v2/quick-scan/file" -Headers @{'accept' = 'application/json'; 'user-agent' = 'Falcon Sandbox' ; 'Content-Type' = 'multipart/form-data' ; 'api-key' = "API_KEY"} -Method Post -Body @{"scan_type" = "all"; "file" = "C:\temp\xyz.jpg" }`

Comment: You're most welcome!